# How to stop my 7 month old Belgian Malinois from biting, grabbing and pulling the garden hose?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, chewing

My 7 month old Belgian Malinois pup has an obsession with the garden hose.  He bites, chews tugs and drags the hose around.  He's like in a trance and doesn't listen.  He will run from one end of the hose back to the hose bib.  He has pulled the bib out of the wall twice. Normally he always listen and behaves.  When he's infatuated with the hose it's like he's possessed.  He can destroy a hose in no time.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Maybe this question would help you: [How can I stop my dog from playing with the hose?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/how-can-i-make-my-dog-stop-playing-with-the-water-hose?rq=1) But in general you need to train with your dog, and treat him every time he reacts (and you know it was hard for him, to chose you ;) against the hose) Maybe a piece of the hose as "his own hose" would help? He is able to differ between his and your hose I assume. (For the "closer": the linked answer is not a duplicate, because it asks about the water, not the hose itself)

Comment: And maybe you want to have a look into [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23521/alternatives-to-walking-a-dog), about entertain and exercise high energy dogs. The Malinois were bred as working dogs, and have a lots of power to fulfill their tasks - or to cause destruction if they are bored ;)

Comment: This kind of obsession is typical to dogs who are bored. I won't close the question because it's technically not a duplicate, but my answer would be identical to the following ones: [Sump pump aggression](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/24118/12501) and [Dog hyper focused on shadows, lights and reflections](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/29576/12501)